# KDB marginal percentages

Tags: kdb

Consider the table T which when tabulated, looks like this:

```
select sum Qty by Flag1,Flag2 from T

Flag1 Flag2 Qty
`Sunny `Hot 20
`Sunny `Cold 40
`Rainy `Hot 60
`Rainy `Cold 80
```

1) Is there a nifty way of computing the overall fraction of aggregate Qty that falls in each bucket (0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4)?  Obviously one could do something like

```
select Qty % sum Qty from select sum Qty by Flag1,Flag2 from T
```

but is there anyway of doing this in one swoop (i.e. with only one select/exec statment),as this could get kind of cumbersome if you're doing this for many variables?

2) Now imagine I want to create a column that has the relative fraction of Qty but marginalized by Flag1.  How do I create the following table?

```
Flag1 Flag2 Qty FracByFlag1
`Sunny `Hot 20  0.333
`Sunny `Cold 40 0.667
`Rainy `Hot 60 0.429
`Rainy `Cold 80 0.571
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) I think it is simplest to sum the quantity of the column separately during division:

```
update (sum Qty) % sum T[`Qty] by Flag1, Flag2 from T
```

2) [fby](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/qsql/#fby) is exactly what you are after:

```
update FracByFlag1: Qty % (sum;Qty) fby Flag1 from T
```

Answer (score 1):

you might want to consider making this a functional form query

[more info on functional form here](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/qsql/)

```
q)t:([]f1:raze 2#'`s`r; f2:4#`h`c; qty:20 40 60 80)
q)p:{![x;();y;enlist[`pct]!enlist (%;z;(sum;z))]}
q)p[t;0b;`qty]
f1 f2 qty pct
-------------
s  h  20  0.1
s  c  40  0.2
r  h  60  0.3
r  c  80  0.4
q)p[t;enlist[`f1]!enlist `f1;`qty]
f1 f2 qty pct      
-------------------
s  h  20  0.3333333
s  c  40  0.6666667
r  h  60  0.4285714
r  c  80  0.5714286
```

Comment: I think you missed the "group by" clause in first query. Problem here is we want ratio of sum qty (by group) to sum qty (of table).I am not sure whether we can do this using one select/exec statement unless we calculate sum qty for whole table separately and use it in query.

Comment: ah, i assumed `t` was already provided with the group sum, and that all he wanted was 1 function that would be versatile enough to calculate what % that constituted of a given grouping (i.e. `0b` for the entire table, versus `enlist[\`f1]!enlist \`f1` for the groups along `f1`

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to weight up the benefits of something "nifty" versus something efficient and easier to read. A double-select might just be the better approach.

One interesting extension is this: what if you need to see the different sub-ratios based on different flags, but all in the same table (and in a single select)? The solution below can achieve that BUT again I stress that this method would be highly inefficient - only showing it for the purpose of being "nifty"

```
q)T:([] Flag1:`Sunny`Sunny`Sunny`Sunny`Rainy`Rainy`Rainy`Rainy;Flag2:`Hot`Hot`Cold`Cold`Hot`Hot`Cold`Cold;Qty:10 10 20 20 30 30 40 40);
q)
q)T
Flag1 Flag2 Qty
---------------
Sunny Hot   10
Sunny Hot   10
Sunny Cold  20
Sunny Cold  20
Rainy Hot   30
Rainy Hot   30
Rainy Cold  40
Rainy Cold  40

q)myGroup:{@[;raze g] raze s%sum each s:sum each flip each y g:group x}
q)
q)select Flag1,Flag2,sum'[Qty],both:sum'[Qty]%sum raze Qty,f1:myGroup[Flag1;Qty],f2:myGroup[Flag2;Qty] from `Flag1`Flag2 xgroup T
Flag1 Flag2 Qty both f1        f2
----------------------------------------
Sunny Hot   20  0.1  0.3333333 0.25
Sunny Cold  40  0.2  0.6666667 0.3333333
Rainy Hot   60  0.3  0.4285714 0.75
Rainy Cold  80  0.4  0.5714286 0.6666667
```

Comment: I agree with _I think you have to weight up the benefits of something "nifty" versus something efficient and easier to read. A double-select might just be the better approach._ Shortest code doesn't always mean efficient or user friendly.